# Task Manager's "Switch to" doesn't work properly on DirectX 8 application on windows 7

Tags: c++, windows-7, directx, taskmanager

Task Manager's "Switch to" doesn't work properly with DirectX 8 application on Windows 7

Hi! I have very specific and strange problem.
My game is using DirectX 8. Main cycle looked something like this:

```
while( WM_QUIT != msg.message  )
{
    if(IsIconic(m_hWnd))
    {
        if(GetMessage( &msg, NULL, 0U, 0U))
        {
            // Translate and dispatch the message
            TranslateMessage( &msg );
            DispatchMessage( &msg );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Use PeekMessage() if the app is active, so we can use idle time to
        // render the scene. Else, use GetMessage() to avoid eating CPU time.
        if(PeekMessage( &msg, NULL, 0U, 0U, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            // Translate and dispatch the message
            TranslateMessage( &msg );
            DispatchMessage( &msg );
        }
        else
        {
            m_pGame->Render();
        }
    }
}
```

The Render function has some basic functionality like this:

```
void CGame::Render()
{
    //...

    HRESULT hr = m_pD3DDevice->TestCooperativeLevel();
    if(hr == D3DERR_DEVICENOTRESET)
        Reset();
    else if( SUCCEEDED( hr ) )
    {
        // Render
        //...
    }

    //...
}
```

In fullscreen, when application loses focus (by Alt+Tab, Windows Button, Ctrl+Shift+Esc etc.) it just minimizes, stay in task bar and doesn't uses any resources. No problem. Then I can activate it by using Alt+Tab or clicking on task bar icon. Also works perfectly: application activates and Resets Direct3D device in fullscreen.
But using Task Manager's “Switch to” feature leads to strange thing: My application window unfolds and then suddenly minimizes again!
I tried to analyze messages input. It's look like my window receives deactivation massage just after the activation message. Like Task Manager activates my application and deactivates it again.

First I tried

```
LockSetForegroundWindow(LSFW_LOCK);
```

It helps on machines with slow motherboard integrated GPU, but strangely it doesn't help on machines with faster GPUs. Some times it works. But most of the time it doesn't.

Then I tried SetForegroundWindow to force-bring my window to foreground:

```
DWORD dwTimeout;
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT, 0, &dwTimeout, 0);
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT, 0, 0, 0);
SetForegroundWindow(hWindow);
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT, 0, (LPVOID)dwTimeout, 0);
LockSetForegroundWindow(LSFW_LOCK);
```

It doesn't help, so I tried another hack:

```
HWND hCurrWnd;
int iMyTID;
int iCurrTID;
hCurrWnd = GetForegroundWindow();
iMyTID   = GetCurrentThreadId();
iCurrTID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hCurrWnd,0);
AttachThreadInput(iMyTID, iCurrTID, TRUE);
SetForegroundWindow(hWindow);
AttachThreadInput(iMyTID, iCurrTID, FALSE);
LockSetForegroundWindow(LSFW_LOCK);
```

Not working.

Why the Task Managers acts so strangely? What else can I do?

///////////////////////////////////////////////////
UPPDATE+SOLUTION.

So, I solve the problem, though I didn't understand completely why it's works.
I find out two solutions. Each of them works for particular set of computers. One for older and weaker computers (or older OS like WindowsXP), and another for more advanced computers with faster videocards and Windows 7. I managed to unite this two solutions and now my game responds to "Switch to" without problems.

For older and weaker computers all I just place LockSetForegroundWindow(LSFW_LOCK) in key places like before main loop start and in WM_ACTIVATE message.

For faster computers I just need to resize my window (made it small) and call for WindowsUpdate when it deactivates. When my window activates again device resets and during device Reset I just restore my window's fullscreen size automatically.

```
LRESULT APIENTRY WndProc(HWND hWnd,UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(message)
    {
    case WM_ACTIVATE:
            if((LOWORD(wParam)==WA_ACTIVE)||(LOWORD(wParam)==WA_CLICKACTIVE))
        {
            if(m_pGame->m_bFullScreen)
                LockSetForegroundWindow(LSFW_LOCK);
            break;
        }
            else
            {
            if(m_pGame->m_bFullScreen)
            {
                SetWindowPos(hWnd,HWND_NOTOPMOST,0,0,
                    128,64,SWP_NOMOVE);
                UpdateWindow(hWnd);
            };
            break;
        };

         //...
        }
}
```

Comment: Also some strange thing. If all other windows are minimized, then Task Manager switches to my window without any problems.